# Переменная не получает данные

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Недавно начал заниматься С# и Unity, решил понять как делать отслеживание мышки (куда мышь туда и камера), написал простенький скрипт.

Переменные `MoveX` и `MoveY` не получают данные от `GetAxis()`, не понимаю в чем проблема, делал все по инструкции, помогите пожалуйста.

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CamLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float SenX = 5f, SenY = 10f;
    private float MoveX, MoveY;

    public Transform Cam;
    public Text X;
    public Text Y;

    private void Update()
    {
        MoveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * SenX;
        MoveY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * SenY;

        X.text = "X = " + MoveX; //Для того что-бы видеть Х
        Y.text = "Y = " + MoveY; //Для того что-бы видеть У
        Cam.Rotate(MoveX, MoveY, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: как вы определили, что `не получают данные`?

Comment: Сразу после получения я вывожу Х и У 

```X.text = "X = " + MoveX; //Для того что-бы видеть Х
        Y.text = "Y = " + MoveY; //Для того что-бы видеть У```

Comment: Это же очевидно, а что выводится то?

Comment: 0 там и там, то есть Х = 0, У = 0

Comment: А вы уверены, что вероятно отличное от нуля значение не затирается сразу нулем? Что если например сделать вот так `if (MoveX != 0) X.text = "X = " + MoveX;`.

Comment: Сделал, теперь Х вообще не выводится

Comment: Проблема была с GetAxis(), заменил его на input.mousePosition и все заработало

Comment: Отлично, если считаете ответ ниже полезным, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оси ***"Horizontal"*** и ***"Vertical"*** по умолчанию отслеживают нажатие клавиш.

Для отслеживания мыши используйте ***"Mouse X"*** и ***"Mouse Y"***.

Или настройте оси на свое усмотрение: **Edit > Project Settings > Input Manager**.

Answer (score 2):

Дополню ответ выше.
[Input.GetAxis()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) возвращает результат от -1 до 1.
По умолчанию существует несколько осей:

- **"Horizontal"** - отслеживает нажатие клавиш, которые в играх используются для перемещения по горизонтали: A=-1, D=1
- **"Vertical"** - то же, но для перемещения вперед-назад: S=-1, W=1
- **"Mouse X"** - отслеживает перемещение мыши влево-вправо. Возвращает отрицательные значения при движении влево, положительные - вправо, чем быстрее движение, тем ближе значение по модулю к единице.
- **"Mouse Y"** - то же, что и "Mouse X", но движение вверх (положительное) - вниз (отрицательное)
- **"Jump"** - возвращает положительное значение при нажатии пробела
- **"Mouse ScrollWheel"** - вращение колесика мыши. Вверх - положительное, вниз - отрицательное, быстрее - больше по модулю.
- **"Submit"** - положительное значение на Enter
- **"Cancel"** - положительное значение на Escape

Вы можете перенастроить их все: изменить названия осей, кнопки, добавить инверсию, чувствительность - в `Edit > Project Settings > Input Manager`.